# Unconstrained nonlinear optimization function

Tags: matlab

I want to optimize an unconstrained multivariable problem using `fminunc` function in MATLAB. Here is an example:

Minimize the function f(w)=x'*A*x

Create a file myfun.m:

```
function f = myfun(x)

f = x'*A*x + b'x
```

Then call `fminunc` to find a minimum of `myfun` near `x0`:

```
[x,fval] = fminunc(@myfun,x0).
```

---

My problem is that in my algorithm, the matrix `A` and vector `b` in myfun.m are not fixed, but can be changed over loops, so I cannot type them by hand. How can I pass values to `A` and `b`?

Comment: why aren't you using [`quadprog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the comments Shai. This is just an example, my problem is actually more complicated, which maximizes the sum of Rayleigh quotients:: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/15960/maximize-sum-of-rayleigh-quotients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options for [passing additional arguments to an objective function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/passing-extra-parameters.html).  For a simple one like yours, you could just make an anonymous function, which will save the values of `A` and `b` when it was created:

```
A = myMatA();
b = myVecb();
myfun = @(x) x.'*A*x + b.'*x;

[x,fval] = fminunc(myfun,x0);  % use no @ with an  anonymous function
```

The other two options are global variables (yuck!) and nested functions. A nested function version looks like this:

```
function [x,fval] =  myopt(A,B,x0) 
[x,fval] = fminunc(@myfunnested,x0);

    function y = myfunnested(x)
        y = x.'*A*x + b.'*x;
    end
end
```

But I think you would not use `fminunc` to solve minimization of `x'Ax + b'x`...

Comment: Hi chappjc, thanks for the suggestion! Acutally, x'Ax + b'x here is just an example, my problem is more complicated, which tries to maximize the sum of Rayleigh quotients: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/15960/maximize-sum-of-rayleigh-quotients. I have used "cellfun" to solve the problem, but it is quite slow. I am trying other method now.